# Foreach loop not display result in Codeigniter View

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter, foreach

I'm trying get multiple records of attendance comment by studentIDs, and ClassID but when i print Array

> Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [attendanceID] => 89 [comment] => This is Yusra ) ) [1] => Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [attendanceID] => 90 [comment] => this is zara butt ) ) [2] => Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [attendanceID] => 91 [comment] => this is ibrahim ) ) [3] => Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [attendanceID] => 92 [comment] => comment ) ) [4] => Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [attendanceID] => 93 [comment] => ) ) [5] => Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [attendanceID] => 94 [comment] => ) ) [6] => Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [attendanceID] => 95 [comment] => ) ) [7] => Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [attendanceID] => 96 [comment] => ) ) )

but i print in view using foreach loop nothing show.. don't know where i'm doing wrong

**Controllor**

```
$studentID = []; // Multiple Student ids
            $comments = [];
            $this->data['set'] = $id; //class id
            $this->data['students'] = $this->student_m->get_order_by_student(array('classesID' => $id, 'schoolyearID' => $schoolyearID));
            foreach($this->data['students'] as $key => $val){
                $studentID[] = $val->studentID; // 
            }
            foreach ($studentID as $student) {
                    $comments[] = $this->sattendance_m->get_comment($id,$student);  
            }
            $this->data['comments']= $comments;
            print_r($comments);
```

**Model**

```
function get_comment($id,$student) {
$this->db->select('attendanceID,comment');
$this->db->where('classesID', $id);
$this->db->where_in('studentID', $student);
$this->db->order_by($this->_primary_key,"desc");
$this->db->limit(1);
$this->db->from($this->_table_name);
$query=$this->db->get();
return $query->result();
}
```

**View**

```
<?php 
if(count($comments)) {
foreach ($comments as $key => $row) {
     echo $row->comment;
    } 
}?>
```

Comment: post entire controller code where you pass data array to view. and just check if($comments) {} instead of if(count($comments)) {}

Comment: add your entire controller taht you mention on your quest. please

Comment: you are using print_r, which method that you used for passing the array from the controller to view ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can see output of `print_r` you have multiple comments per student. So you need to do inner loop again

```
if(count($comments)) 
{
  foreach ($comments as $key => $row) {
     foreach ($row as  $value) {
       echo $value->comment;
     }
  } 
}
```

Comment: thank you. but see my new problem  Nested loop repeating value in html td.  [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47141765/nested-loop-repeating-value-in-html-td)

Answer (score 0):

this should be

```
<?php

$i=0;
if($comments)
{
  foreach ($comments as $key => $row) {
    echo $key[$i++]->row
  } 
}else{
echo "null";
}


?>
```