# Nested loop repeating value in html td

Tags: arrays, codeigniter, foreach

my result showing
[image]

but i Want 
[image]

**MY controller**

```
if((int)$id) {
                $studentID = [];
                $comments = [];
                $this->data['set'] = $id;
                $schoolyearID = $this->session->userdata('defaultschoolyearID');
                $this->data['classes'] = $this->student_m->get_classes();
                $this->data['students'] = $this->student_m->get_order_by_student(array('classesID' => $id, 'schoolyearID' => $schoolyearID));
                foreach($this->data['students'] as $key => $val){
                    $studentID[] = $val->studentID; 
                }
                foreach ($studentID as $student) {
                        $comments[] = $this->sattendance_m->get_comment($id,$student);  
                }
                $this->data['comments'] = $comments;
$this->load->view('_layout_main', $this->data);
```

**MY Modal**

```
function get_comment($id,$student) {
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->where('classesID', $id);
$this->db->where_in('studentID', $student);
$this->db->order_by($this->_primary_key,"desc");
$this->db->limit(1);
$this->db->from($this->_table_name);
$query=$this->db->get();
return $query->result();
}
```

**My VIEW**

```
 <?php foreach($students as $student) { ?>
                                                <tr>


                                                    <td data-title="<?=$this->lang->line('attendance_name')?>">
                                                        <?php echo $student->name; ?>
                                                    </td>
                                                    <td data-title="<?=$this->lang->line('attendance_roll')?>">
                                                        <?php echo $student->roll; ?>
                                                    </td>



<td data-title="<?=$this->lang->line('attendance_comment')?>">
<?php 
if(count($comments)) 
{
$attendanceID = [];
$student_ID = [];
$comment = [];
$classid = [];
  foreach ($comments as $key => $row) {
     foreach ($row as  $value) {
        $attendanceID [] = $value->attendanceID;
        $student_ID [] = $value->studentID;
        $classid [] = $value->classesID;
        //$comments [] = $value->comment;   
$key = array_search($student->studentID,$student_ID); //find same StudentID ids
$key2 = array_search($set,$classid); // find same classID

if($student_ID[$key] == $student->studentID && $set == $classid[$key2]){
        ?>
         <?php
           echo $value->comment; // Showing Comment where Both IDs same
         ?>
<?php }
     }
  }
}

?>
    </td>
                                                    <?php } ?>
                                               </tr>
                                            <?php  } ?>
```

I want match Student Id & ClassID  and show related Comment of studentID, but in this code as you seeing all Comment Repeating same  ,, might be because of nested loop but don't know how to fix this problem and  where I'm doing wrong .

Answer (score 0):

Create array of comment with use of student_id. So repeating and conflict not done.

IN your **controller** chnage your comment for loop as below:

```
foreach ($studentID as $student) {
    $comments[$student] = $this->sattendance_m->get_comment($id,$student);  //<---add $student as index
 }
```

Then in your **view** change comment foreach as below

```
foreach ($comment[$student->studentID] as $key => $row) {
     foreach ($row as  $value) {
        $attendanceID [] = $value->attendanceID;
        $student_ID [] = $value->studentID;
        $classid [] = $value->classesID;

         echo $value->comment; // Showing Comment 

      }
}
```